# How to create a new thread each time the user hits the download button

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, urllib, python-multithreading

I am new to python and I am creating this app in python using **tkinter and urllib**. Basically, the program gets the URL, name, format and the path of the file then downloads it whenever the user hits the "Download" button. The problem is that without threading the program freezes until the download is finished and I don't want that to happen. So after a bit of research, I found out that threading can help solve this problem. After using threads, I found out that I can start a thread only once meaning that the user can only download one file.So I figured out that in order for the user to download multiple files and at a time, whenever the user hits the download button the program should create a new thread for that download and this even gives the user the ability to download multiple files at a time. The problem is that I have no clue how to write this algorithm. I would really appreciate it if someone helped me.
My code without threading:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import font as tkFont
import random
import urllib.request
import requests
import wget


def printsth():
    print("Yay it works! ")


def main_menu():
    root = Tk()
    root.title('8-bit downloader ')
    root.iconbitmap(r"C:\Users\rayanravesh\PycharmProjects\GUI_Calculator\icon.ico")
    root.geometry("600x300")
    # the top menu
    num = IntVar()
    chum = IntVar()
    var = IntVar()
    menu = Menu(root)
    root.config(menu=menu)
    submenu = Menu(menu)
    menu.add_cascade(label="Settings", menu=submenu)

    def custom_op():
        custom = Toplevel()
        custom.iconbitmap(r"C:\Users\rayanravesh\PycharmProjects\GUI_Calculator\icon.ico")
    submenu.add_command(label="Customization ", command=custom_op)

    def settings_op():
        global gps
        set_win = Toplevel()
        set_win.iconbitmap(r"C:\Users\rayanravesh\PycharmProjects\GUI_Calculator\icon.ico")
        path_label = Label(set_win, text="Current default download path: ")
        path_entry = Entry(set_win, width=30)
        file_read = open('Data.txt', 'r')
        data_base = file_read.read()
        path_entry.insert(0, data_base)
        file_read.close()

        def default_output():
            global location
            file_read2 = open('Data.txt', 'r+')
            file_read2.truncate(0)
            file_read2.close()
            write_file2 = open('Data.txt', 'w')
            write_file2.write(path_entry.get())
            write_file2.close()
            location = path_entry.get() + "\\"
            default_location = location.replace("\\", "\\\\")
        path_btn = Button(set_win, text="Submit ", command=default_output)
        path_label.pack(anchor=CENTER, expand=1)
        path_entry.pack(anchor=CENTER, expand=1)
        path_btn.pack(anchor=CENTER, expand=1)
    submenu.add_command(label="Settings ", command=settings_op)
    submenu.add_separator()
    submenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.destroy)

    # the section menu
    editmenu = Menu(menu)
    menu.add_cascade(label="Sections(soon)", menu=editmenu)
    editmenu.add_command(label="Downloader", command=printsth)
    editmenu.add_command(label="Converter", command=printsth)
    editmenu.add_command(label="Media Player", command=printsth)
    editmenu.add_command(label="Editor", command=printsth)
    # the tool bar
    toolbar = Frame(root, bg="light gray")
    insert_button = Button(toolbar, text="Insert an image", command=printsth)
    insert_button.pack(side=LEFT, padx=2, pady=2)
    print_button = Button(toolbar, text="Print", command=printsth)
    print_button.pack(side=LEFT, padx=2, pady=2)
    toolbar.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)

    # the download function
    def download_image():
        global formatname
        if num.get() == 1:
            name = random.randrange(1, 1000000)
        else:
            name = str(name_entry.get())
        formatname = str(format_entry.get())
        if var.get() == 1:
            operator = str(url_entry.get())
            formatname = '.' + operator[-3] + operator[-2] + operator[-1]
        else:
            pass
        fullname = str(name) + formatname
        url = str(url_entry.get())
        fw = open('file-size.txt', 'w')
        file_size = int(requests.head(url, headers={'accept-encoding': ''}).headers['Content-Length'])
        fw.write(str(file_size))
        fw.close()
        path = str(output_entry.get()) + "\\"
        if chum.get() == 1:
            filee = open('Data.txt', 'r')
            destination = filee.read()
            path = destination + "\\"
            output_entry.insert(0, destination)
            filee.close()
        else:
            output_entry.delete(0, END)
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, path.replace("\\", "\\\\") + fullname)

    # the status bar
    status_bar = Label(root, text="Downloading...", bd=1, relief=SUNKEN, anchor=W)
    status_bar.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)

    # the download frame
    body_frame = Frame(root, bg="light blue")
    download_button = Button(body_frame, text="Download! ", command=download_image, border=3, width=20, height=5)
    download_design = tkFont.Font(size=12, slant='italic')
    download_button['font'] = download_design
    download_button.pack(side=LEFT, pady=5, padx=5)
    body_frame.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)
    # the main interaction menu
    inter_frame = Frame(root)
    url_entry = Entry(inter_frame, width=30)
    label = Label(inter_frame, text="Enter the image URL: ")
    file_format = Label(inter_frame, text="Choose your file format: ")
    format_entry = Entry(inter_frame, width=30)
    file_name = Label(inter_frame, text="File's name: ")
    name_entry = Entry(inter_frame, width=30)
    check_name = Checkbutton(inter_frame, text="Give a random name", variable=num)
    check_format = Checkbutton(inter_frame, text="Download with default format", variable=var)
    check_default = Checkbutton(inter_frame, text="Download to default path", variable=chum)
    check_default.deselect()
    output_path = Label(inter_frame, text="Choose output path: ")
    output_entry = Entry(inter_frame, width=30)
    file_name.pack(anchor=CENTER, expand=1)
    name_entry.pack(anchor=CENTER, expand=1)
    check_name.pack(anchor=CENTER, expand=1)
    label.pack(anchor=CENTER, expand=1)
    url_entry.pack(anchor=CENTER, expand=1)
    file_format.pack(anchor=CENTER, expand=1)
    format_entry.pack(anchor=CENTER, expand=1)
    format_entry.insert(0, '.')
    check_format.pack(anchor=CENTER)
    output_path.pack(anchor=CENTER, expand=1)
    output_entry.pack(anchor=CENTER, expand=1)
    check_default.pack(anchor=CENTER, expand=1)
    inter_frame.pack(expand=1)
    root.mainloop()

    # the end!


main_menu()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code, you can simply change the following line in `download_image()` function:

```
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, path.replace("\\", "\\\\") + fullname)
```

to:

```
threading.Thread(target=urllib.request.urlretrieve,
                 args=(url, path.replace("\\", "\\\\")+fullname), daemon=True).start()
```

Of course, you need to `import threading`.

---

**UPDATE:** to make `download_image()` run in thread, add a function:

```
def start_download():
    threading.Thread(target=download_image, daemon=True).start()
```

and set the `command` option of `download_button` to this new function:

```
download_button = Button(body_frame, text="Download!",
                         command=start_download, border=3, width=20, height=5)
```

Comment: Hi @acw1668, The code above works multiple times but the program still freezes for a couple seconds. I believe that the entire function should become a thread not just the urllib.request.urlretrieve. If you know any alternatives please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the code snippet! It really made my day!